# How to clean up waiting requests after Selenium webdriver connection timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hi I have question about Selenium hub capacity/waiting for slots

Using docker-selenium:

- hub: selenium/hub:3.141.59-zirconium
- node: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.141.59-zirconium
- python lib: selenium==3.141.0

Python connection code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection

def connect(hub_url, capabilities, chrome_options):
    RemoteConnection.set_timeout(3)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        hub_url, desired_capabilities=capabilities, options=chrome_options,
    )

    return driver
```

at first run its OK, but with second code is waiting for free slots and
after 3 seconds I'm getting connection timeout from `selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py` (thats fine). But request is pending = in Grid Console there is info:

`1 requests waiting for a slot to be free.
Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [load-extension=/extension], extensions: []}, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., version: }`

After releasing the slot, chrome is starting with `data:,` in url and nothings happend. Thats why I want to clean pending requests on timeout.

**How to remove this waiting request on connection timeout ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to clean this waiting requests. But maybe is better to use server timeout than client timeout. So use `newSessionMaxWaitTimeInSeconds` flag when running Selenium instead of client timeout.

That's solves most of my problems right now.